# Selecting a forms “select” option based on referring URL

Tags: html, php, web-development, css, jquery

I have a *seemingly* simple question that I can’t find an answer for.

**Scenario:**

I am developing a *”single-page”* website based on a ***HTML5*** UP! template that shows/hides content after clicking a button on the main menu.

I would like to have it such that a user who visits the ***Services*** page, finds a *package* they’d like to book, clicks the related button for the service and is then taken to the ***Contact*** page with the **Subject** select ***automatically*** selected based on their choice.

Is this possible/simple? I’d be grateful for any pointers.

**Site in Progress:**

- **[Adept Nutrition Care](https://dev2.adeptnutritioncare.com)**

**HTML5 Up Template:**

- **[Dimension](https://html5up.net/dimension)**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "how do I code something" questions should be asked at StackOverflow.com.   Before you ask there, you should include what you have tried and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok thanks Stephen. I wasn’t sure where the appropriate place to post this was. I’ll reword and post it there.